# Require approval only for the first content that a user submit

Tags: users

My Drupal 7 site just went live.

In my site, there is an option the register regularly (Drupal core way), and with social login (hybridauth).

Currently, only authenticated users can post content and comments on my site.
Unfortunately, I already have many fake users publishing content on my site.

I want to be able to approve content for new users, but only for the first 3 pieces of content.
After that, if I approved 3 pieces of content for the user (which mean I trust him), I want to allow him to post any content he wants, without any need for approval.

How can I achieve my goal?
Can I do that automatically - meaning that after I approved 3 pieces of content - the user will automatically  be able to post content without approval?

Comment: Have you tried creating two roles, one for untrusted (default) then second for trusted. Then create a rule that checks number of approved comments and if 3+ then change the user to the trusted role.

Comment: It is the mollom or honey pot modules.. Now I need to dig in and see what is the problem. I entered a great content as authenticated user (not administrator) and still the content is unpublished.